# Stacked bar graph with proportion on y axis instead of count

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using the `gss_cat` tibble from `forcats` (`tidyverse`), and the first thing I decided to plot was race x income. So I did a bar plot, but it turns out the total of surveyed people is not the same for each race:

```
gss_cat %>%
  filter(!rincome %in% c("No answer", "Don't know", "Not applicable")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = race, fill = rincome))+
  geom_bar(position = "stack")+
  #coord_polar(theta = "y")+
  theme_classic()+
  scale_fill_viridis_d(direction = -1)
```

[image]

The same happens with a pie chart (so without that `#` at `coord_polar`):
[image]
So I thought I do `y = ..prop..`, which theoretically would use the proportion instead of the total, but this seems to make everything the same:

```
gss_cat %>%
  filter(!rincome %in% c("No answer", "Don't know", "Not applicable")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = race, y = ..prop.., fill = rincome))+
  geom_bar(position = "stack")+
  #coord_polar(theta = "y")+
  theme_classic()+
  scale_fill_viridis_d(direction = -1)
```

[image]
I then tried doing `group = race`, which in my experience works for `geom_count`, but it didn't for this:

```
gss_cat %>%
  filter(!rincome %in% c("No answer", "Don't know", "Not applicable")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = race, y = ..prop.., fill = rincome, group = race))+
  geom_bar(position = "stack")+
  #coord_polar(theta = "y")+
  theme_classic()+
  scale_fill_viridis_d(direction = -1)
```

[image]
It just threw the `fill` out the window entirely. There was no warning.

Why is this happening and how can I change it? I didn't find anything on R Documentation, the [ggplot2 homepage](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/), [this website – which is one of my favorites](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/)... I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Could you please `dput(gss_cat)` and add to the post to reproduce your issue?

Comment: It's native to the `forcats` package.

Comment: I have added a possible solution for your issue. I hope that can help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `position=fill`:

```
library(forcats)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#Code
gss_cat %>%
  filter(!rincome %in% c("No answer", "Don't know", "Not applicable")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = race, fill = rincome))+
  geom_bar(position = "fill")+
  #coord_polar(theta = "y")+
  theme_classic()+
  scale_fill_viridis_d(direction = -1)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's it! I tried googling for the `position`s available but didn't find it... Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm trying. It says I still have to wait 1 minute. I guess you were too fast... :P